# Brownie run error ImportError: functoolz.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _PyGen_Send (Arch linux)

Tags: python, brownie

I had a problem installing brownie using pipx, so I used `python3 setup.py install brownie`

now that I try to run 'brownie' I get import error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/unchained/.local/bin/brownie", line 5, in <module>
    from brownie._cli.__main__ import main
  File "/home/unchained/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/brownie/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from brownie.project import compile_source, run
  File "/home/unchained/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/brownie/project/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .main import (  # NOQA 401
  File "/home/unchained/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/brownie/project/main.py", line 44, in <module>
    from brownie.network import web3
  File "/home/unchained/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/brownie/network/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .account import Accounts
  File "/home/unchained/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/brownie/network/account.py", line 12, in <module>
    import eth_account
  File "/home/unchained/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eth_account/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from eth_account.account import (  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/unchained/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eth_account/account.py", line 8, in <module>
    from cytoolz import (
  File "/home/unchained/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cytoolz/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .functoolz import *
ImportError: /home/unchained/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cytoolz/functoolz.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _PyGen_Send
```

I already installed cytoolz and cython and cpython

```
pip install cytoolz, pip install cython, pip install cpython
```

I'm unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar error today, and after much hassle found a working solution,

if you are not adamant on using pipx then pip seems to solve the issue, otherwise :
run ->

```
pipx list
```

you'll get output like " eth-brownie.. installed using Python 3.10.x"
There's someting wrong with support of brownie with 3.10 as of now, so install a downgraded version of python for your OS (I'm sure you know how, or google it).

```
 pipx uninstall eth-brownie
```

to remove it, and reinstall it using downgraded version, I used 3.9(You can use your preferred version, but 3.9 seems to work fine for the moment)

```
pipx install --python python3.9 eth-brownie
```

you can use the "--force" flag, but there won't be any need to do so.

and voila, run

```
brownie --version
```

You'll get the output..

> Brownie v1.18.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum .

Enjoy!!